# Label using VBscript in ArcMap - multiple IF statements?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, query, vbscript

I have 4 fields that hold number values.  I only want a label returned if the field <>0.  For instance, if col1<>0, then label = col1 AND if col2 <>0 then label = col2, etc.  So, I want all four columns to show up as labels, but only if they are not equal to 0.
I have tried finding info online and am having issues.  Thought maybe everyone could help.
The following script works, but only for one at a time.  I need to combine them so that this script works with Seq2, Seq3 and Seq4.  I am thinking there is a way to do multiple IF statements?

```
Function FindLabel ( [Seq1_TractDepthSequence], [Seq1_BegInterval] ,[Seq1_EndInterval], [Seq1_DeckCorpRITot], [Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] , [Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] , [Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]   )
if ( [Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ([Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0) then
  FindLabel = [Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] &" RI"
end if
End Function
```

The following won't work:

```
Function FindLabel ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence], [_Seq1_BegInterval] ,[_Seq1_EndInterval], [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot], [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]   )
if ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ([_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0) then
  FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] &" RI"
if ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ( [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot]  <> 0) then
  FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] &" ORRI
if ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ( [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot]  <> 0) then
  FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] &" CorpInt"
if ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ( [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]  <> 0) then
  FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot] &" WI"
else
end if
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code was failing was you had multiple "if" statements without an "end if" for each of them. It looks like you wanted "elseif" for the second, third, and fourth checks.

```
Function FindLabel ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence], [_Seq1_BegInterval] ,[_Seq1_EndInterval], [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot], [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]   )
  if ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ([_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0) then
    FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] &" RI"
  elseif ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ( [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot]  <> 0) then
    FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] &" ORRI
  elseif ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ( [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot]  <> 0) then
    FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] &" CorpInt"
  elseif ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1) AND ( [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]  <> 0) then
    FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot] &" WI"
  else
  end if
End Function
```

Since you're always checking whether the _Seq1_TractDepthSequence field is = 1, try something like this to condense the code.

```
Function FindLabel ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence], [_Seq1_BegInterval] ,[_Seq1_EndInterval], [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot], [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]   )
  if [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1 then
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0 then
      FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] &" RI"
    elseif [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot]  <> 0 then
      FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] &" ORRI
    elseif  [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot]  <> 0 then
      FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] &" CorpInt"
    elseif [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]  <> 0 then
      FindLabel = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "& [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot] &" WI"
    end if
  end if
End Function
```

Based on your comment below, try this code.

```
Function FindLabel ( [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence], [_Seq1_BegInterval] ,[_Seq1_EndInterval], [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot], [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]   )
  if [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1 then
    label = [_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0 then label = label & [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] &" RI "
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot]  <> 0 then label = label & [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] &" ORRI "
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot]  <> 0 then label = label & [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] &" CorpInt "
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]  <> 0 then label = label & [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot] &" WI"
    FindLabel = label
  end if
End Function
```

Comment: If using the above code, will it return a value for all 4 FindLabel results, if there is a case where none of them = 0?

Comment: Do you mean that if more than one field is greater than zero, you would want multiple fields in the label (such as Beginning Interval - End Interval : 45 RI, 12 ORRI, 2 CorpInt, 32 WI)? Could you modify your original question to show what types of output you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.  I was getting "0 RI 0 ORRI 25 CorpInt 12 WI".  I wanted to remove the "0" and text portions to get "25 CorpInt 12 WI" only.

Comment: Check to see if the code I added above does what you want

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several ways to do this, but maybe the simplest is to just build the label with all values, 0 included, then replace the 0's with empty spaces. Although honestly your function doesn't look like it's doing what you state. It looks like you're passing in seven fields, not four.

Not as familiar with VBScript as I used to be, but you could try something like the following in Python. You might have to adjust things a bit to fit your data.

```
def FindLabel(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4):
    lbl = ' '.join(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
    lbl.replace('0', '')
    return lbl
```

Comment: If I replace the 0 with a blank, that does not solve my problem, because then my label would still have the string of "RI" (or other) floating out in the label by itself.  I want it to only put in the label string if the value is not 0 and I want it to put in four label strings based on the value of 4 fields.  (yes, more than 4 fields are being used, but that does not interfere with my question)

Comment: Well, that's why I said you might have to adjust things to fit your data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get it to work! It only provides the label string if the query is true.

```
Function FindLabel ( [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot], [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot]    )
  strExp1 =  [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] &" RI"
  strExp2 =  [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot]  &"  CorpInt"
if ([_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0) then  strExp = strExp1
if ([_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] <> 0) then   strExp = strExp2
  FindLabel = strExp 
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to add this updated code to your original question as an edit.

Comment: What if both if statements are true? You'll default to the second value. You may be relying on only one being true in your data, but unless there's some constraint to enforce that, it's not a reliable method. Then again, maybe you want to default to the second value if both are true, in which case you're ok.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would try:

Simply export the selection for your query and turn on labeling.
So your SQL query would be something like

```
(_Seq1_TractDepthSequence = 1 AND [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0) OR
(_Seq1_TractDepthSequence = 1 AND [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot]  <> 0) 

...etc
```

Then export the selection. Your new layer will only contain those that are not = 0. 
You could then specify what needs to be labelled or create a separate "labelfield" with what you want labelled inside... OR...

I would go the lazy route and add a "LabelField" since your code seems redundant.
In the calculate field:

```
[_Seq1_BegInterval] &" - "& [_Seq1_EndInterval] &" : "
```

And for your label modified from kenbuja:

```
 Function FindLabel ( [LabelField],[_Seq1_TractDepthSequence], [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot], [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] , [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]   )
  if [_Seq1_TractDepthSequence] = 1 then

    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] <> 0 then Findlabel = [LabelField] & [_Seq1_DeckCorpRITot] &" RI "
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot]  <> 0 then Findlabel = [LabelField] & [_Seq1_DeckCorpORRITot] &" ORRI "
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot]  <> 0 then Findlabel = [LabelField] & [_Seq1_DeckCorpIntTot] &" CorpInt "
    if [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot]  <> 0 then Findlabel = [LabelField] & [_Seq1_DeckCorpGWITot] &" WI"
    FindLabel = [LabelField]
  end if
End Function
```